# Fecebook Messenger Bot in PHP doesn't always respond to user

Tags: php, facebook, bots, messenger

I have relatively simple Facebook Messenger bot in php for research purposes:

```
$access_token = "xxxxxxx";
$challenge = $_REQUEST['hub_challenge'];
$verify_token = $_REQUEST['hub_verify_token'];

if ($verify_token === 'MY_VERIFICATION_TOKEN') {
  echo $challenge;
}

$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

$sender = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['sender']['id'];
$message = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message']['text'];

$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token='.$access_token.';

$ch = curl_init($url);

if($message=="hi")
{
        $jsonData = '{
        "recipient":{
                "id":"'.$sender.'"
        },
    "message":{
            "text":"hello!"
    }
    }';
}

$jsonDataEncoded = $jsonData;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

and my cron job is same as in developer guide

```
curl -ik -X POST "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/subscribed_apps?access_token=xxxxxx"
```

So basically, nothing besides connection and one response.
When i personally send "hi" (as a page owner and app owner), my bot always responds correctly, but when other people try to say hi - bot sometimes responds, sometimes not (usually not, in 5 cases bot responded once)

Additionally, when i visit my script url, it gives me error:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#100) The parameter recipient is required","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"DvrO1UEw5BJ"}}
```

Please help me to set this right.

Comment: "*for research purposes*" Nice *disclaimer* ;)

Answer (score 6):

This might also happen if you forget to set the content-type as well.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem and this worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Only users listed as **Admins** or **Developers** or **Testers** in your app roles (https://developers.facebook.com/apps/YOUR_APP_ID/roles/) can interact with your chat bot webhook. It won't be available to other users unless your app is approved by Facebook and publicly available. From the [Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/app-review):

> When you're ready to release your app to the public, it must go through an approval process. This will walk you through the submission process and also acceptable and unacceptable usage.

About your second question, Facebook sends an API call to your webhook in the form of JSON data which includes **sender id** & **recipient id** in the HTTP request body. But when you visit your webhook manually, you don't have  those parameters in your request body so **$sender** will be empty in your case. And that's why the CURL request to Facebook API fails with the error "The parameter recipient is required" because `"recipient":{"id":"'.$sender.'"},` will be empty.

If you want to try your webhook manually, use actual **recipient id**, something like:

**Curl Command:**

```
curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"object":"page","entry":[{"id":43674671559,"time":1460620433256,"messaging":[{"sender":{"id":853241244787916},"recipient":{"id":43674671559},"timestamp":1460620433123,"message":{"mid":"mid.1460620432888:f8e3412003d2d1cd93","seq":12604,"text":"Testing Chat Bot .."}}]}]}' https://YOUR_WEBHOOK_URL_HERE
```