# Facebook Messenger bot in PHP, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, facebook, api, messenger

**UPDATE:** I rewrote this script 4 times, and I understand the mechanism, but unfortunately I don't understand what's missing.. The error code is the same..

```
<?php
// parameters
$hubVerifyToken = 'XXXXXX';
$accessToken = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
// check token at setup
if ($_REQUEST['hub_verify_token'] === $hubVerifyToken) {
echo $_REQUEST['hub_challenge'];
exit;
}
// handle bot's anwser
$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$senderId = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['sender']['id'];
$messageText = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message']['text'];
$answer = "I don't understand. Ask me 'hi'.";
if($messageText == "hi") {
  $answer = "Hello";
}
$response = [
  'recipient' => [ 'id' => $senderId ],
  'message' => [ 'text' => $answer ]
];
$ch = curl_init('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token='.$accessToken);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($response));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
//based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36803518
```

But if I open the API's page, I get the following error message:

```
{
 "error": {
 "message": "(#100) The parameter user_id is required",
 "type": "OAuthException",
 "code": 100,
 "fbtrace_id": "G8FOo08+EsE"
 }
}
```

If `user_id` is missing, where and how can I write in it? What `user_id` should I use? PHP codes are not possible to use anymore? should I use for example the [this site](http://manychat.com) instead of PHP?

Comment: `So, I found this PHP code in a video tutorial` - voila, you identified the problem. The issue you're having is that you're trying to do something without understanding the API behind it. Now you're looking for quick solution, and that's going to get you nowhere. So, are you after a copy paste code that you can just dump in your script and forget about it or are you after understanding how all of this should work?

Comment: After that I "copy paste" the code, I went through a lots of videos, forums and the whole FB for Developers site, and I still not really understand the mechanism.. I'm so sorry about it, but I deal with it. So if you give me a stronghold, then I surely can do it. Anyway, I thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$response = [
  'recipient' => [ 'user_id' => $senderId ],
  'message' => [ 'text' => $answer ]
];
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it does not work for me.. :(