# Facebook Messenger Bot: How to remember conversation (maintain the context)?

Tags: php, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm new to this topic, and therefore i just tried [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36803518/fecebook-messenger-bot-in-php-doesnt-always-respond-to-user). And then it is perfectly working.

But the problem is with the Conversation / Context.

Now the bot only works perfectly to the **very last message** from user. But it cannot know what the earlier one(s), and therefore cannot maintain the conversation, since i don't know how to **retrieve** the previous/last messages in proper way.

### My bot's behaviour right now (example)

```
User: Hi, nice to meet you. Blah blah...
Bot: Sorry i don't understand you. Please key-in the Item Code to see details:
User: A1234
Bot: Item Details: xxx xxxx xxxxx xxxxx
Bot: Which "color" you want to order?
User: Blue
Bot: Sorry i don't understand you, Please key-in the Item Code to see details:
```

As you can see (in the last part of messages), the Bot loses the Context (Conversation) after the User's follow-up reply. Cannot link to the previous message(s).

How to solve this issue please?

Answer (score 0):

You could keep a context stack for each user, pushing an item on top of the stack for each message sent by the bot and matching context in FIFO order for each message recieved.

[Bot-context](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bot-context) is a cool library which provides an easy way to maintain context. The related [blog post](https://medium.com/@ashishshubham/maintaining-context-in-chatbots-2016b6a5b7c6#.4b10epgv6).